# Access out of bounds error in EXTI_Init function

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32

I'm trying to use external interrupt in my STM32f407. I'm using `PD0` for it. But when executing function `EXTI_Init` I'm getting error "Access out of bounds: Access 0x40013c00-0x40013c04 Bounds 0x00000000-0x00000000". This happens on line `*(__IO uint32_t *) tmp |= EXTI_InitStruct->EXTI_Line;`. Have anybody met this stuck already?

Here is the code:

```c
/* Set variables used */
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStruct;
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStruct;

/* Enable clock for GPIOD */
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
/* Enable clock for SYSCFG */
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG, ENABLE);

/* Set pin as input */
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* Tell system that you will use PD0 for EXTI_Line0 */
SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(EXTI_PortSourceGPIOD, EXTI_PinSource0);

/* PD0 is connected to EXTI_Line0 */
EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Line0;
/* Enable interrupt */
EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
/* Interrupt mode */
EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
/* Triggers on rising and falling edge */
EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Rising_Falling;
/* Add to EXTI */
EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStruct);

/* Add IRQ vector to NVIC */
/* PD0 is connected to EXTI_Line0, which has EXTI0_IRQn vector */
NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI0_IRQn;
/* Set priority */
NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x00;
/* Set sub priority */
NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x00;
/* Enable interrupt */
NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
/* Add to NVIC */
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStruct);
```

Comment: The line you say the error is on doesn't appear in the source you've included.

Comment: STM32 Standart Peripheral Library file stm32f4xx_exti.c contains it. I made no changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. There was option named "Check accesses" checked in IAR Project Options->Runtime Checking->C-RUN Runtime Checking->Enable->Track pointer bounds. Unchecking the option solved the problem.